# Unable to read first row from Excel using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlbulkcopy

I am using following code to update an Excel file into SQL Server. Code is working but it is not able to insert first row into table.

```
OleDbConnection OleDb = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
OleDbCommand OleDbCmm = new OleDbCommand(Query,OleDb);
OleDbDataReader OleDbdr;
OleDb.Open();

if (OleDb.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    OleDbdr = OleDbCmm.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy BulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString());
    BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TempTable";

    if (OleDbdr.Read())
    {
       BulkCopy.WriteToServer(OleDbdr);
    }
 }

 OleDb.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Even I was facing same problem, this is because I was using `Read()` Method like below.

```
while (dr.Read()) {
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

Solution to above problem is remove `dr.Read()` method and while loop 
use 
`bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr)`
without any condition and `Read()` Method.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason for this may be that you've indicated in your connection string that first row contains column names (`HDR=YES`) thus that row is not treated as containing data.

**EDIT**

Another possible reason for this would be the call to `OleDbDataReader.Read()` method before passing the reader to `SqlBulkCopy` object. [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The copy operation starts at the next available row in the reader. Most of the time, the reader was just returned by ExecuteReader or a similar call, so the next available row is the first row.

Thus, in your case you should not call `OleDbdr.Read()` because this advances the reader to the first row; you should let `BulkCopy` call `Read()` and it will start reading from the first row.
Your code should be:

```
OleDbdr = OleDbCmm.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy BulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString());
BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TempTable";
BulkCopy.WriteToServer(OleDbdr);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am using following connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + FilePath + "'; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\""

Answer (score 1):

You need to set header for the Excel to sql as I have done in my

```
string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + Your D S+ ";" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(conn);
using (sSourceConnection)
{
   DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
   string[] SheetNames = GetExcelSheetNames(strFileName);
   string[] preColumnHeader = new string[]{ "CarrierId", "StateId", "TerrCd", "ProgramId", "ClassId",
   "PremTypeID","Limit50_100", "Limit100_100", "Limit100_200", "Limit300_300", "Limit300_600", 
   "Limit500_500","Limit500_1mil", "Limit1mil_1mil", "Limit1mil_2mil", "OtherParameter" };
   sSourceConnection.Open();
   string strQuery = string.Empty;
   strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetNames[0] + "]";

   OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, sSourceConnection);
   oleDA.Fill(dtExcelData);
   sSourceConnection.Close();
   string[] colName = new string[dtExcelData.Columns.Count];
   int i = 0;
   foreach (DataColumn dc in dtExcelData.Columns)
   {
       colName[i] = dc.ColumnName;
       i++;
   }
   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connStr))
   {
       bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_test";
       bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
   }
}
```